# navigate from random widget to a new widget which uses whole screen

Tags: flutter, dart

My question is if it is possible to navigate from any widget inside random other widgets to a widget which uses the whole screen. For example from a widget inside a column to a new widget which not only uses the space of the widget in the column but the whole screen.
Thanks for help!

Comment: Is this what you are looking for?
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/PageRoute/fullscreenDialog.html

Comment: Yeah thanks a lot!